# Why unsortedArray is changing while my code running?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the given `unsortedArray` array. Before that I need to do following steps. But it always take the number 9 and then repeat number 8

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int unsortedArray[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

    int arr1[9];
    int arr2[9];

    int arr1Counter = 0;
    int arr2Counter = 0;

    int i;int n;
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){

        // n = unsortedArray[i];

        int j;
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){

            if(unsortedArray[j] != unsortedArray[i]){

                if(unsortedArray[j] > unsortedArray[i]){

                    arr2[arr2Counter] = unsortedArray[i];
                    arr2Counter++;

                }else{

                    arr1[arr1Counter] = unsortedArray[i];
                    arr1Counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int k;
    for(k=0; k<9; k++){
        printf("%d ", unsortedArray[k]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ultimately after sometime you will have out of bound access to `arr1` and `arr2` which will result in undefined behavior and you are seeing the result of it, that is `unsortedArray` contents are getting modified.

Comment: A debugger is your best friend here. Yes we could help you, but learning to debug is a wonderful skil in programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior because `arr2[9]` overflows. In your nested loop, this part

```
arr2[arr2Counter] = unsortedArray[i];
arr2Counter++;
```

Gets executed 36 times. As a result, you have out of bounds access, which causes undefined behavior. On my machine, `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` is printed, but the program then crashes because the stack is corrupted.

Consider the logic of your program. The part inside `for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {` is executed a total of `72` times, and each time an entry is added to `arr1` or `arr2`. They can both hold `10` values each, so they can't hold all `72` values.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it changing? Because `arr1Counter` or `arr2Counter` (or both) can get bigger than the size of the arrays you use them to access.

With less details:

```
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++){
             //maybe increment either here
        }
    }
```

That could go way above 9.
So, you can corrupt data.